# The issue of using Do-While loop in C++?

Tags: c++, do-while

I have tried to list prime numbers using C++ Do-While loop but I have trouble and not found problems inside my code. Can any one help me in this?

I have tried so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int num2check = 3, innerCheck;
bool isPrime;
do
{
  isPrime = true;
  innerCheck = 2;

  while ((innerCheck < num2check) && (isPrime == true));
  {

    if (num2check % innerCheck == 0)
    {
     isPrime = false;
     break;
    }
      else 
      {
       innerCheck++;
      }
  }
  if (isPrime == true)
  {
  cout << num2check << " is prime.";
  num2check++;
  }
  else
  {
  num2check++;
  }
}while(num2check < 50);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: remove the semicolon here `while ((innerCheck < num2check) && (isPrime == true))`

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code line by line and the answer should be extremely obvious.

Comment: It's worth noting that in newer versions of `gcc` (6 and later, I believe), this will get a warning if compiled with `-Wall`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the semicolon in this line

```
 while ((innerCheck < num2check) && (isPrime == true));
```

In programming standards, the `;` signifies an end of statement, or in this case that it is a null statement, so here the `while` loop doesn't executes anything and keeps on running in infinite loop as the condition will always holds true